# How to play Burnout Paradise on two screens without "unifying" the desktop?

Tags: burnout-paradise

I have two screens and use them heavily for work; I absolutely require the ability to maximize an application to take just one screen.

Burnout Paradise has a dual-screen mode which works fine if I "unify" my screens (can't remember the term for that). This means that a maximized window spans both screens, unfortunately.

Switching between the modes is too much of a hurdle and I end up playing on just one screen. Is there an easier way?

(I have an ATI card and if I just enable two screens in Burnout what I get instead is a single screen with a rather squished image)

Comment: Should this be migrated?  The game doesn't really have any significant impact on the question.

Comment: @Gnome it's hard to say. It really depends on the solution. If the solution is generic, like Chris's, then migrate. But I can envisage some DirectX hack too, in which case it belongs here. I really think there's too much fragmentation in SE...

Comment: I think that perhaps the game tag should be removed at least.

Comment: @Gnome you are most welcome to edit the question in any way you see fit. It doesn't seem like there is a usable answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I've not tested it with Burnout Paradise, but as a general productivity tool I can definitely recommend Ultramon: http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/windows.asp 
.It has a variety of features around window management/taskbar configuration but in-particular it can add a button to application title bars that will maximise them across multiple monitors.

You'd have to purchase it but I think they have a trial.

Comment: Ultramon does not work with span mode.